# Breakpoints on s390x

Tags: c, linux, gdb, mainframe

I'm working in GDB on S390x

I have a function that essentially does this:

```
Item *getItemFromRef( PrimaryDataStructure pds, size_t ref ) {
    Item *returnValue = NULL;
    SecondaryDataStructure sds = getSecondaryFromPrimary(pds, ref)
    if (sds) {
        returnValue = getItemFromRefSecondary(sds, ref);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I've set breakpoints on `getItemFromRef` and `getItemFromRefSecondary`.  The `getItemFromRef` breakpoint fires fine, but the `getItemFromRefSecondary` never fires.  Is this expected?  Is there any way to get it to fire?  What am I doing wrong?  This behavior occurs even if I disable the breakpoint for `getItemFromRef`.

EDIT: Using gdb 6.8.50

Comment: "*the `getRefFromSecondary` never fires*" -- the code you've posted never **invokes** `getRefFromSecondary`!

Comment: @Robᵩ Quite right.  I updated the question to fix the names of the breakpoint locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took another look at the symbols today and discovered that two different dynamic libraries were importing the same function symbol and that the break point was being set to the wrong version of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that `getItemFromRefSecondary` got inlined at that point?  It may report the inlined function name when you step into it (due to debug information) but the debugger can only break if it's truly a function call.

You can compile with less optimization (or none, with `-O0`) or if that's too intrusive you can force the function to not inline with `__attribute__((__noinline__))` (assuming you build with `gcc`).

Comment: I must admit I'm not completely comfortable with 390 assembler, but it looks like there's an explicit branch to `getItemFromRefSecondary`.  Also, the program isn't built with debugging symbols and there is an explicit symbol, for what it's worth.